# Telegram Bot API file access via Google Sheets Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, telegram-bot

How to transfer a local photo file to google drive using multipart/form-data?

I have copied local files to google drive, obtained the google drive file link but following code line hangs and an error comes up related to the html???

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(vUrlTelegram + "/sendPhoto?chat_id=" + chat_id + "&photo=" + photoUrl );
```

note:
have obtained html string for a sample photo from the internet, and the following telegram bot google api javascript code works

```
function sendPhoto( chat_id, photoUrl ) {
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(vUrlTelegram + "/sendPhoto?chat_id=" + chat_id + "&photo=" + photoUrl );
console.log(response.getContentText());
```

}

Telegram doco

Photo to send.
Pass a file_id as String to send a photo that exists on the Telegram servers (recommended),
pass an HTTP URL as a String for Telegram to get a photo from the Internet, or
upload a new photo using multipart/form-data. More info on Sending Files »

Comment: Can you describe the error you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- From your question, when the direct link of image in the internet is used for the following script, you can confirm that the script works.

  ```
    function sendPhoto( chat_id, photoUrl ) {
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(vUrlTelegram + "/sendPhoto?chat_id=" + chat_id + "&photo=" + photoUrl );
      console.log(response.getContentText());
    }
  ```

From this situation, when you want to use the image file on Google Drive for above script, how about the following flow?

#### Flow:

1. Publicly share the image file on Google Drive as `Viewer` of `Anyone with the link`.
2. Use `webContentLink` of the image file as `photoUrl`.

   - In this case, when the file ID of the image file is used, `webContentLink` is as follows.

     ```
       https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id={fileId}
     ```

#### Sample script:

For example, When the image file is publicly shared and run `UrlFetchApp.fetch` and sharing image file is stopped, the script is as follows.

```
var fileId = "###"; // Please set the file ID of the image file.
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId)

file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);  // Image file is publicly shared.

var photoUrl = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + fileId;
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(vUrlTelegram + "/sendPhoto?chat_id=" + chat_id + "&photo=" + photoUrl );
console.log(response.getContentText());

// Utilities.sleep(2000); // I'm not sure whether this is required for this situation.
file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE, DriveApp.Permission.NONE);  // Sharing image file is stopped.
```

#### References:

- [Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files)
- [setSharing(accessType, permissionType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setsharingaccesstype,-permissiontype)

Comment: a/
function sendPhoto( chat_id, photoUrl ) {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(vUrlTelegram + "/sendPhoto?chat_id=" + chat_id + "&photo=" + photoUrl );
    console.log(response.getContentText());  
}
works, because I've tested the photo html link

1.1/ YES this link works
https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/soccer-match-brazil-flamengo-september-th-brazilian-professional-championship-scene-game-teams-atletico-mineiro-126975226.jpg

1.2/ NO, this link does NOT work

Comment: @Trajano Roberto Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your replying. Can I ask you about the detail of it? I would like to confirm it.

Comment: it is working now, after I've changed the google drive folder to :Anyone with the link", Viewer

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I could understand about it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.